# What wifi cards will work out of the box for desktop computers?

Tags: wireless, hardware

I am planning on getting rid of all my wired connections in the house and switching everything over to wifi. My question pertains specifically to desktop computers, *not* laptops!

So my questions are

1) What wifi cards are proven to work, out of the box, with the latest version of ubuntu without needing to install additional software?

2) What are the known issues with each one (range issues, configuration issues etc

3) And if there isn't a solid out of the box choice, what are good alternatives that may require drives be installed but have minimal fuss to do so?

4) All other considerations aside, what would be recommended as best choice if convenience and ease of installation was not an issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported) is a link to a list that contains a lot (not most, just a lot) wifi cards and their support info.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that the list doesn't contain most cards - these days, there should probably be just a list of *unsupported* ones.